# Multiple iterations

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration, coding-style

Is there a easier, cleaner way to write code like this:

```
(1..10).each do |i| 
  (1..10).each do |j|
    (1..10).each do |k|
      (1..10).each do |l|
         puts "#{i} #{j} #{k} #{l}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Ideally I'd be able to do something like...

```
(1..10).magic(4) { |i, j, k, l| puts "#{i} #{j} #{k} #{l}" }
```

Or even better...

```
magic(10, 4) { |i, j, k, l| puts "#{i} #{j} #{k} #{l}" }
```

If there's not something built in, how would I write a method like the last one?

Comment: what output do you expect? is it something like `1 2 3 4 \n 5 6 7 8 \n 9 10` or `0 0 0 1 \n 0 0 0 2 ...`?

Comment: @nash No; the first code runs on its own. If you adjusted all `(1..10)` to `(0..9)` then you would get `'0 0 0 0', '0 0 0 1',...'9 9 9 8', '9 9 9 9'`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226895/combine-array-of-array-into-all-possible-combinations-forward-only-in-ruby/5227021#5227021 , but I like this question's answers better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're on Ruby 1.9, you can do this:

```
range = (1..10).to_a
range.repeated_permutation(4) do |set|
  puts set.join(" ")
end
```

In Ruby 1.8:

```
range = (1..10).to_a
range.product(range, range, range).each do |set|
  puts set.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: Or even `range.product([range]*3).each …`

Answer (score 2):

dmarkow's solution (I believe) materializes the ranges which, at least in theory, uses more memory than you need.  Here's a way to do it without materializing the ranges:

```
def magic(ranges, &block)
  magic_ = lambda do |ranges, args, pos, block|
    if pos == ranges.length
      block.call(*args)
    else
      ranges[pos].each do |i|
        args[pos] = i
        magic_.call(ranges, args, pos+1, block)
      end
    end
  end
  magic_.call(ranges, [nil]*ranges.length, 0, block)
end

magic([1..10] * 4) do |a,b,c,d|
  puts [a, b, c, d].inspect
end
```

That said, performance is a tricky thing and I don't know how efficient Ruby is with function calls, so maybe sticking to library functions is the fastest way to go.

**Update**: Took Phrogz' suggestion and put `magic_` inside `magic`.  (**Update**: Took Phrogz' suggestion *again* and hopefully did it right this time with `lambda` instead of `def`).

**Update**: `Array#product` returns an `Array`, so I'm assuming that is fully materialized.  I don't have Ruby 1.9.2, but Mladen Jablanović pointed out that `Array#repeated_permutation` probably doesn't materialize the whole thing (even though the initial range is materialized with `to_a`).

Comment: `repeated_permutation` shouldn't materialize whole array when called without block, but an Enumerator instead, which you then can traverse using `each`, without creating large structure in memory (hopefully).

Comment: I almost wrote this form, but got lazy when thinking about the recursion. :) Note, however, that with something like this I advocate creating a local `magic_` lambda inside your `magic` method and letting it recursively call itself. With this there is no namespace pollution for an unwanted extra method. +1 for a very general solution, however.

Comment: I appreciate that you took my suggestion, but what you've done does not nest the functions. It defines a new outer `magic_` function each time you run the `magic` method! Instead, I was suggesting: `def magic(...); magic_ = lambda{ |r,a,p,b| ... magic_[ ... ] }; magic_[ ... ]; end`

Comment: @Phrogz: Whoops!  I guess I assumed it worked like Python.  Fixed now, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken the liberty of changing the order of your `magic` parameters under the assumption that base 10 is more common and optional:

```
def magic(digits,base=10)
  raise "Max magic base of 36" unless base <= 36
  (base**digits).times do |i|
    str   = "%#{digits}s" % i.to_s(base)
    parts = str.scan(/./).map{ |n| n.to_i(base)+1 }
    yield *parts
  end
end

magic(3,2){ |a,b,c| p [a,b,c] }
#=> [1, 1, 1]
#=> [1, 1, 2]
#=> [1, 2, 1]
#=> [1, 2, 2]
#=> [2, 1, 1]
#=> [2, 1, 2]
#=> [2, 2, 1]
#=> [2, 2, 2]

magic(2,16){ |a,b| p [a,b] }
#=> [1, 1]
#=> [1, 2]
#=> [1, 3]
#=> ...
#=> [16, 15]
#=> [16, 16]
```

**Explanation**:

By translating the original problem from `1..10` to `0..9` and concatenating the digits we see that the output is just counting, with access to each digit.

```
0000
0001
0002
...
0010
0011
0012
...
9997
9998
9999
```

So that's what my code above does. It counts from 0 up to the maximum number (based on the number of digits and allowed values per digit), and for each number it:

1. Converts the number into the appropriate 'base':
   `i.to_s(base)            # e.g. 9.to_s(8) => "11", 11.to_s(16) => "b"`
2. Uses [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001127) to pad the string to the correct number of characters:
   `"%#{digits}s" % ...     # e.g. "%4s" % "5" => "   5"`
3. Turns this single string into an array of single-character strings:
   `str.scan(/./)           # e.g. " 31".scan(/./) => [" ","3","1"]`
   *Note that in Ruby 1.9 this is better done with `str.chars`*
4. Converts each of these single-character strings back into a number:
   `n.to_i(base)               # e.g. "b".to_i(16) => 11,  " ".to_i(3) => 0`
5. Adds 1 to each of these numbers, since the desire was to start at 1 instead of 0
6. Splats this new array of numbers as arguments to the block, one number per block param:
   `yield *parts`

Comment: This is really cool. Could you maybe explain the `str =` and `parts =` lines? I'm having a hard time following them.

Comment: @Drew I've update the answer with an explanation of how it works.