# Creating permutations from a multi-dimensional array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following multi-dimensional array in Ruby:

```
[[1,2], [3], [4,5,6]]
```

I need to have the following output:

```
[[1,3,4], [1,3,5], [1,3,6], [2,3,4], [2,3,5], [2,3,6]]
```

I have tried creating a recursive function, but I'm not having much luck.

Are there any Ruby functions that would help with this? Or is the only option to do it recursively?

Thanks

Comment: You should always show the code you've tried, even when it didn't work. Sometimes the fix is a minor tweak. Other times you'll get alternate solutions. Always, we'll be able to tell whether you've actually tried something or are just fishing for answers.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yup, [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000291) does just that ([Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)):

```
a = [[1,2], [3], [4,5,6]]
head, *rest = a # head = [1,2], rest = [[3], [4,5,6]]
head.product(*rest)
#=> [[1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6]]
```

Another variant:

```
a.inject(&:product).map(&:flatten)
#=> [[1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6]]
```