# Multiplying the contents of two arrays (not the arrays themselves)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make an array with every card in the deck, so it would be ["Ac", "Ad", "Ah", "As", "Kc", ...] though order is not important.

Isn't there a way that inject could be used to solve this problem?  This was as close as I could get.

```
cards = ["A", "K", "Q", "J", "T", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"] 
suits = ["c", "s", "d", "h"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :025 > cards.inject(suits) { |suit, card| suit.map{|s| "#{card}#{s}"}}
 => ["23456789TJQKAc", "23456789TJQKAs", "23456789TJQKAd", "23456789TJQKAh"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you aim to do?

```
cards.map { |card|
  suits.map { |suit| "#{card}#{suit}" }
}.flatten
```

Comment: wanted to use inject, but yeah this was a solution I'd had.  for some reason whenever i see a case that inject makes sense to me, i just end up using map.

Answer (score 4):

Or maybe something similar to

```
cards.product( suits ).map(&:join)
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use `inject` but thought worth mentioning: [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-product). See answer to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5582579/1964078)